# Changing material on clipping plane

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

The material of section plane in Forge is as standard the fully colored faces with a hatch, while the section box has a transparent material (or no material at all?)

Is it possible to change between these, or in some way create own material to use on clipping planes?

I create the clipping planes through code already with

```
this.SectionExtension.tool.setSectionPlane(finalNormal, point)
```

Thanks for any pointers that could lead in the right direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the viewer doesn't support change cap mesh materials since there is no API for this purpose. To remove cap meshes, I would advise you to set cut planes via [Viewer3D#setCutPlanes](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/GuiViewer3D/#setcutplanes-planes).

For creating your own section box, you can refer to my answer here: [How can I create section box in forge viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385734/how-can-i-create-section-box-in-forge-viewer), then you should be able to use this box to construct a box geometry for applying your won materials inside the viewer [overlay](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/custom-geometry/) or via the [scene builder](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/scene-builder/).

Comment: We want to change because of situations where we have objects inside objects. Those are not visible with the normal section plane tool.
And on the other hand, the section box we would also be useful is the sectioned faces could have a material too. 
So both ways would be useful for both tools.

Comment: For creating your own section boxes, please see my answer above

Comment: Thank you for the advice Eason. I will look more into this.