# Autodesk Forge clip view: How show/hide the boundaries box of clip view?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I created an extension to generate clip views.
After creating the clip, is it possible to show/hide the clip view outline?
I would like the view to remain clipped, but the user cannot interact with (select) the walls of the clipped view.

Comment: Are you talking about a Section Box?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385734/how-can-i-create-section-box-in-forge-viewer

Comment: Yes @AdamNagy: am looking for that. Thank you!

Comment: It seems that if you create the clip view programmatically using setCutPlanes() outside the Section Analysis tool - as shown in the referenced stackoverflow post - then the cut planes are not shown