APS Viewer, section box as scope box
When using the section box, is it possible to isolate or select the elements inside the section box?
Trying to select elements of the same type after having used the section box but elements out of the box gets selected too.
How can I limit the scope of the operation to only the elements inside the box?

One suggestion is to retrieve the bounding box of the section box and utilize the functions provided by THREE.Box3 (e.g., containsBox, containsPoint, intersectsBox) to identify objects within the box. Additionally, you may need to verify whether the identified objects are hidden by using model.getInstanceTree().isNodeHidden(dbId).
https://gist.github.com/yiskang/d3c088f2633228a474301ce68f764c68
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59385734/how-can-i-create-section-box-in-forge-viewer
